# How to install OpenvSwitch in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation

How can I install OpenvSwitch in ubuntu 16.04.
It is not in the repositories.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried and which errors are you getting? Just saying "can't" won't help anyone.

Comment: I'm sorry. I edited the question. I have trouble installing. I could not find the right guidance

Comment: I just started with OVS :(

Comment: It's okay. GIve me about 1 hour I will answer the question in case no one else will have answered.

Comment: OpenVSwitch [are in repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=amd64&searchon=names&keywords=openvswitch). Please add output of `apt-cache policy openvswitch-switch openvswitch-test` to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Direct installation

Run these commands

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install openvswitch-switch
```

Then start the ovs deamon

```
sudo ovs-vswitchd
```

---

### Manual installation

#### 1. Download OpenvSwitch

Create a directory (folder) in your Desktop called `ovs` then download https://www.openvswitch.org/releases/openvswitch-2.5.6.tar.gz from OpenVSwitch website and save it in the `ovs` folder. This is important because of step 3 below.

Extract it by right clicking on it and selecting `extract` or run the commands below in the terminal one at a time:

```
cd ~/Desktop/ovs/
tar -xvf openvswitch-2.5.6.tar.gz
```

#### 2. Install dependencies

OpenVSwitch requires some dependencies installed first. Run this command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt install build-essential fakeroot graphviz autoconf automake bzip2 debhelper dh-autoreconf libssl-dev libtool openssl procps python-all python-qt4 python-twisted-conch python-zopeinterface module-assistant dkms make libc6-dev python-argparse uuid-runtime netbase kmod python-twisted-web iproute2 ipsec-tools openvswitch-switch racoon
```

Confirm if all dependencies are installed. The command below should return nothing if all are installed. Otherwise it will tell you which ones are missing. This command should be run inside the openvswitch directory extracted above:

```
sudo dpkg-checkbuilddeps
```

#### 3. Generated OpenVSwitch .deb files

You have two options, use either of the commands below depending on whether you want to run the unit tests or not.

a. Run the unit tests

```
sudo fakeroot debian/rules binary
```

b. Don't run the unit tests

```
sudo DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS='parallel=8 nocheck' fakeroot debian/rules binary
```

This will generate the following debs in the ~/Desktop

```
openvswitch-common_2.5.6-1_amd64.deb
openvswitch-datapath-dkms_2.5.6-1_all.deb
openvswitch-datapath-source_2.5.6-1_all.deb
openvswitch-dbg_2.5.6-1_amd64.deb
openvswitch-ipsec_2.5.6-1_amd64.deb
openvswitch-pki_2.5.6-1_all.deb
openvswitch-switch_2.5.6-1_amd64.deb
openvswitch-test_2.5.6-1_all.deb
openvswitch-testcontroller_2.5.6-1_amd64.deb
openvswitch-vtep_2.5.6-1_amd64.deb
```

#### 4. Install the generated deb files

The most important ones are openvswitch-common and openvswitch-switch. The rest can be installed depending on your exact needs.

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i ../openvswitch-common_2.5.6-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i ../openvswitch-switch_2.5.6-1_amd64.deb
```

The openvswitch daemon called `ovs-vswitchd` will run automatically. You can confirm using:

```
ps -ef | grep ovs
```

Which should return such an output

```
ovsdb-server: monitoring pid 24477 (healthy)
ovsdb-server /etc/openvswitch/conf.db -vconsole:emer -vsyslog:err -vfile:info --remote=punix:/var/run/openvswitch/db.sock --private-key=db:Open_vSwitch,SSL,private_key --certificate=db:Open_vSwitch,SSL,certificate --bootstrap-ca-cert=db:Open_vSwitch,SSL,ca_cert --no-chdir --log-file=/var/log/openvswitch/ovsdb-server.log --pidfile=/var/run/openvswitch/ovsdb-server.pid --detach --monitor
ovs-vswitchd: monitoring pid 24487 (healthy)
ovs-vswitchd unix:/var/run/openvswitch/db.sock -vconsole:emer -vsyslog:err -vfile:info --mlockall --no-chdir --log-file=/var/log/openvswitch/ovs-vswitchd.log --pidfile=/var/run/openvswitch/ovs-vswitchd.pid --detach --monitor
```

Unless it isn't running, you can manually start it using:

```
sudo ovs-vswitchd
```

#### 5. Documentation

This information plus the documentation can be found at http://www.openvswitch.org/support/dist-docs-2.5/

Comment: Direct Installation seems pretty easy.