# Need help with a Netplan configuration issue

Tags: networking, server, permissions

When I did `sudo netplan apply`, it shows me permission warnings.
Below are the same exact messages shown by the terminal.

```
** (generate:2496): WARNING **: 05:24:24.943: Permissions for /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml are too open. Netplan configuration should NOT be accessible by others.

** (generate:2496): WARNING **: 05:24:24.943: Permissions for /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml are too open. Netplan configuration should NOT be accessible by others.
Cannot call openvswitch: ovsdb-server.service is not running.

** (process:2494): WARNING **: 05:24:25.215: Permissions for /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml are too open. Netplan configuration should NOT be accessible by others.

** (process:2494): WARNING **: 05:24:25.215: Permissions for /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml are too open. Netplan configuration should NOT be accessible by others.

** (process:2494): WARNING **: 05:24:25.296: Permissions for /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml are too open. Netplan configuration should NOT be accessible by others.

** (process:2494): WARNING **: 05:24:25.296: Permissions for /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml are too open. Netplan configuration should NOT be accessible by others.

** (process:2494): WARNING **: 05:24:25.296: Permissions for /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml are too open. Netplan configuration should NOT be accessible by others.

** (process:2494): WARNING **: 05:24:25.296: Permissions for /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml are too open. Netplan configuration should NOT be accessible by others.
```

`stat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`:

```
  File: /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
  Size: 117         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 253,0   Inode: 787924      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2023-07-10 00:36:05.082334425 +0000
Modify: 2023-06-12 09:56:02.404864248 +0000
Change: 2023-06-12 09:56:02.404864248 +0000
 Birth: 2023-06-12 09:56:02.404864248 +0000
```

A clearer version for the stat netplan command: https://www.coderstool.com/cs/Yf7XHb

`cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s1:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

Clearer snippet: https://www.coderstool.com/cs/3HwyVa

I have continued with "sudo systemctl start isc-dhcp-server" , "sudo systemctl enable isc-dhcp-server", then "sudo systemctl status isc-dhcp-server". Below are the results of the commands.

Command snippet: https://www.coderstool.com/cs/bF69W4

Comment: stat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
  File: /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
  Size: 117        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 253,0 Inode: 787924      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2023-07-10 00:36:05.082334425 +0000
Modify: 2023-06-12 09:56:02.404864248 +0000
Change: 2023-06-12 09:56:02.404864248 +0000
 Birth: 2023-06-12 09:56:02.404864248 +0000

Comment: That's strange - permissions look correct compared to my system. 

Comment: I have attached the Stat netplan command results. I'm so lost right now. I can't seem to configure it... T.T

Comment: What's not working? You know it's only a warning, right - it's not an error..

Comment: The status of my dhcp server has failed once I have done with configuring the netplan configurations. I have updated my question. Feel free to have a look. Also, thanks a lot for your replies!

Comment: the DHCP servers may be unrelated. What happens when you start it manually? I *suspect* that the order the services are started in are 'wrong' - but I just ended up going back to the classic /etc/networks setup before I got around to digging further

Comment: Also "Cannot call openvswitch: ovsdb-server.service" is not running. seems worth focusing on

Comment: Try `sudo chmod -R o-rwx /etc/netplan/`, which removes access of "others". Can it be that this is Ubuntu in a virtual environment or similar ?

Comment: I have the same permissions on my `01-network-manager-all.yaml` and when I do `sudo netplan apply`, it gives me the same warning (four times). Nevertheless, the network works fine.

Comment: Need to install OVS first. Follow [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128111/how-to-install-openvswitch-in-ubuntu-16-04) and you should be fine.

Answer (score 15):

`chmod 600 /etc/netplan/your_config_file.yaml` should solve your problem.  Do this for every netplan file that was listed in the warnings.

Comment: It says operation not permitted. How do I get around this?

Comment: try with sudo, you will get rid of operation permitted issue. But chmod solution didn't work for me.

Comment: It worked. Thanks. +1