# How to avoid netplan apply errors for Ubuntu22?

Tags: network-bonding

How to avoid netplan apply errors for Ubuntu22?

```
WARNING: permissions for /etc/netplan/00 are too open
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need help with a Netplan configuration issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1477287/need-help-with-a-netplan-configuration-issue)

Answer (score 2):

Netplan configs from Ubuntu 20.04 (and possibly later, but definitely earlier) will have default permissions of `0644`, but the default should now be `0600` ([as stated here in the documentation](https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/)) to not trigger this warning (and it's not an **error**, there is somewhat of a difference. ).

Set the proper permission with `chmod` - should be `0600`:

```
sudo chmod 0600 /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
```

Keeping permissions to `0644` will work, but it's probably better to set permissions to the designated default of `0600`.

Comment: Or rather `chmod 0600` to get rid of the warning ... It should only need `rw` for owner user which is supposed to be `root`

Comment: Ok it seems from another question (linked as dupe) that Canonical indeed changed the default permissions from `0644` to `0600` it seems..

Comment: I remember reading it only needs `0600` in netplan specs a while ago and I've been looking for it since I added my comment above and still searching for documentation, but I'm sure about it ... or at least that's what my memory is telling me :)

Comment: I have just tested `0644` on Ubuntu 23.04 and that still prints a warning, but `0600` doesn't.

Comment: Found some: https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/

Comment: And in the source itself https://github.com/canonical/netplan/blob/main/src/netplan.c#L1163